# DataGridView-when I press enter it goes to the next cell

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

i have a datagridview with 5 columns,when i press "enter" it goes to the next cell and when it arrives to the end of the rows when i press enter it adds a new rows,but my problem is when i move to the previous rows after i press enter it jumps the rows and does not go to the next cells,any help?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static int Col;
    public static int Row;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();           
    }   

    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {           
        Col = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X;        
        Row = dataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y;     
    }

    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.KeyChar == (int)Keys.Enter)
        {              
            if (Col + 1 < 5)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[Col + 1, Row];
            }
            else
            {                        
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[Col - 4, Row + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Forget about CellEnter event and the Form1_KeyPress event also. Just handle the **dataGridView1_KeyDown** event like this:

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
            {
                col ++;
            }
            else
            {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }

            if (row == dataGridView1.RowCount)
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col, row];
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Please note that I changed the code a bit, and remember to set the Handled event property to true, otherwise it will process the default behavior.

Cheers!

Comment: Reinaldo thank you very much for your answer,there is another quastion i wanaa ask you,for editing a cell i have to press enter twice,the first time for inserting my data into cell and the second time for moving to another cell,is there any way by pressing one enter it do the two jobs?i mean when i end my typing into a cell after i press one enter it goes to the next cell???and i wanaa ask you could explain what is e.handled=true?thanks anyway

Comment: You can handle the dataGridView1_CellEnter event and add dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);

Comment: my friend there is a another problem,lets think i got 3 rows and 3columns,i entered a data into row1 and column1 after i go to the next row and entering data when i get back to the row1 for editing a data i press enter it jumps to the next row:( it's driving me crazy.i don't want to jump to the next row i want to go to the next column

Comment: Yes, that is the default behavior. To solve that, override the ProcessCmdKey in your form like this: protected override bool 


    ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m,
    System.Windows.Forms.Keys k)
    { 
       if (m.Msg == 256 && k == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter)
       {
                dataGridView1.EndEdit();
       }
       return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref m, k);
    }

Comment: My friend thx alot,could you expain for me what does this ovverride method does??

Comment: Overriding the ProcessCmdKey method allows you to process the keys before they are sent to the form or any other controls. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx

Answer (score 4):

this works for me

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        {                
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            int row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
            int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
bool notlastColumn = true;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    int icolumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    int irow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    int i = irow;
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (icolumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
             //dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            if (notlastColumn == true)
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
            }
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, irow + 1];
         }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[icolumn + 1, irow];
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
    //below is for escape key return
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    //below is for enter key return 
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);     
}
```

Just copy and paste the code.

Only thing you should have grid in your form.

Comment: not work for hidden columns , give exception Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell.

Answer (score 1):

because the keyDown envent will not fire when press enter on datagridview cell this will be best thanks to @Nagarjun

```
bool notlastColumn = true;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg,System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
int icolumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int irow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int i = irow;
if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
{
    if (icolumn == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
    {
         //dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        if (notlastColumn == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];
        }
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[0, irow + 1];
     }
    else
    {
        // to pass hidden cell, because will fire exception
        //exception: Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell
        // the do while loop will enable you to pass any hidden cell
         do
          {
            icolumn++;
          } while (!dgv[icolumn, irow].Visible);
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[icolumn, irow];
    }
    return true;
}
else
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
        return true;
    }
//below is for escape key return
return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is handle the KeyDown event to check if the return key is pressed, you cancel the event and tell the application to use the selected index of +1 in your datagridview:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
   {
      int column = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
      int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[column, row+1];
      e.Handled=true;
   }
}
```

To prevent problems you should also insert a clause to check if there are items available after the one the user pressed return.

Answer (score 0):

Using this solution:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtg.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        int iCol = dtg.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int iRow = dtg.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (iCol == dtg.ColumnCount - 1)
            {
                if (iRow + 1 == dtg.RowCount)
                {
                    dtg.Rows.Add();
                }

                dtg.CurrentCell = dtg[0, iRow + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                dtg.CurrentCell = dtg[iCol + 1, iRow];
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            Close();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Good Luck ...

Answer (score 0):

Just move to right when key press is enter...

```
private void datagridview_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)        
{   
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
          SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
     }
}
```

Comment: You should consider adding a description of what your code is doing as just a code dump is not particularly informative.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked well for me

```
 bool notlastColumn = true;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
    {
        int icolumn = dgvReceDet.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int irow = dgvReceDet.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int i = irow;
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (icolumn == dgvReceDet.Columns.Count - 1)
            {
                //dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                if (notlastColumn == true)
                {
                    dgvReceDet.CurrentCell = dgvReceDet.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                }
                dgvReceDet.CurrentCell = dgvReceDet[0, irow + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                // to pass hidden cell, because will fire exception
                //exception: Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell
                // the do while loop will enable you to pass any hidden cell
                do
                {
                    icolumn++;
                }
                while (icolumn <= dgvReceDet.Columns.Count - 1 && !dgvReceDet[icolumn, irow].Visible);
                if (icolumn <= dgvReceDet.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    dgvReceDet.CurrentCell = dgvReceDet[icolumn, irow];
                }
                else
                {
                    SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
                    SendKeys.Send("{HOME}");
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
        else
            if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
            return true;
        }
        //below is for escape key return
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```