# How to transfer Datagridview edit control to the next cell of the selected row when we press Enter Key

Tags: forms, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview, ado.net

I am using this Code in `dataGridView1_SelectionChanged` and `dataGridView1_CellEndEdit` event. It works properly but when I press the enter Key firstly the edit control focus jumps on new row of selected column and then automatically goes back to the upper row and select the next cell. But I want to transfer directly to the next cell of the selected row.

For more details I attached a picture.

[image]

Please help me. I am trying a lot of logic for this.

Here my code

```
try
{
    if (MouseButtons != 0) return;

    if (celWasEndEdit != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
    {
        // if we are currently in the next line of last edit cell
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == celWasEndEdit.RowIndex + 1 &&
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex)
        {
            int iColNew;
            int iRowNew = 0;
            if (celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex >= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
            {
                iColNew = 0;
                iRowNew = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            }
            //if we Edit the cell and press Enter the focus on the next cell
            else
            {
                iColNew = celWasEndEdit.ColumnIndex + 1;
                iRowNew = celWasEndEdit.RowIndex;
            }
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[iColNew, iRowNew];
        }
    }
    celWasEndEdit = null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extended control derived from the *DataGridView* and override the *ProcessDialogKey()* method.

For additional information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873361/datagridview-enter-key-event-handling).

### **Test sources**

**User control:**
using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace DGNextEdit
{
    public class UpdatedDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                var col = CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                var row = CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (col >= ColumnCount - 1 && row < RowCount - 1)
                    row++;

                CurrentCell = this[col < ColumnCount - 1 ? col + 1 : 0, row];
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test form:**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace DGNextEdit
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test form code-behind:**

```
namespace DGNextEdit
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new DGNextEdit.UpdatedDataGridView();
            this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.Column3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Column1,
            this.Column2,
            this.Column3});
            this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 261);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Column1
            // 
            this.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
            this.Column1.Name = "Column1";
            // 
            // Column2
            // 
            this.Column2.HeaderText = "Column2";
            this.Column2.Name = "Column2";
            // 
            // Column3
            // 
            this.Column3.HeaderText = "Column3";
            this.Column3.Name = "Column3";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private UpdatedDataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column3;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working. i am also check your link. i am using both logic but its not working can you give me the whole logic...

Comment: can we use this                                                      ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData) in dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

Comment: It is too late to control row changing in _dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(...)_. I will put all test sources to the remark. Run it and check, that it works.

Comment: I just have added your code to _dataGridView1_SelectionChanged_ and _dataGridView1_CellEndEdit_ events processing and everything works fine. Though there is no need in this code. What is purpose of the _celWasEndEdit_ variable?

Comment: Yes i said that this is working all right but my problem is when i press Enter key the focus goes to below cell of the next row and then automatically back to the upper row and selected the next cell. Each time when i edit the cell of the Currentrow the edit control changing the row position and then working all right. but i want to develop that when i press enter key edit control selected the next cell without leaving the row