# How to get the enter value when key press in datagrid row cells in Winform C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

When Onkeypress in windows form datagrid row cell how to get the entered value when keypress for row level calculation?

```
Answer:



 private void Grid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Grid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                // This fires the cell value changed handler below
                Grid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }
```

I have completed by above events.Let me know if you have any other way to archive the requierments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView "Enter" key event handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873361/datagridview-enter-key-event-handling)

Comment: Not Working.....

Comment: May be CellEndEdit event helps you get the changed cell value.

Comment: I have completed by CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event