# how to use enter key after cell edit in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

im trying to go next cell in datagridview after typing in the cell but it go to next row in same Column
** if not typing any thing in cell it working fine
how can solve that

```
private void dgvacc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                
                int row = dgvacc.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                int col = dgvacc.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;


                try
                {
                    if (col < dgvacc.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        dgvacc.CurrentCell = dgvacc.Rows[row -1].Cells[col + 1];
                        dgvacc.Focus();
                    }
                    else if (col == dgvacc.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {

                        dgvacc.CurrentCell = dgvacc.Rows[row].Cells[0];
                        dgvacc.Focus();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }



        }
```

Comment: You can use Tab key to navigate to next cell in the same row. Are you trying to override this behavior with Enter Key?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9676758/14171304 Remove the `if (row == dataGridView1.RowCount) dataGridView1.Rows.Add();` part.

Comment: Are you trying to override this behavior with Enter Key?    yes  
Abhinav Pandey

Comment: @dr.null same with me nothing change when type in the cell

Comment: You wanna jump to the next cell while **typing**? What requirement is that? Or maybe you mean jump to the next cell on press any key **if** the current cell **is not** in edit mode?

Comment: @dr.null no -- when i finish typing and press enter it jump to next cell in another row (same Column ) but i want it to jump next cell in same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all
i found the the answer and it solve it - thanks again

```
private DataGridViewCell dgvEndEditCell;
        private bool _EnterMoveNext = true;

        [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
        public bool OnEnterKeyMoveNext
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EnterMoveNext;
            }
            set
            {
                this._EnterMoveNext = value;
            }
        }


private void dgvacc_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int iColumn = dgvacc.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = dgvacc.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (iColumn == dgvacc.Columns.Count - 1 && iRow != dgvacc.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    dgvacc.CurrentCell = dgvacc[0, iRow + 1];
                }
                else if (iColumn == dgvacc.Columns.Count - 1 && iRow == dgvacc.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    dgvacc.CurrentCell = dgvacc[iColumn + 1, iRow];
                }
            }


        }



private void dgvacc_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._EnterMoveNext && MouseButtons == 0)
            {
                if (this.dgvEndEditCell != null && dgvacc.CurrentCell != null)
                {
                    if (dgvacc.CurrentCell.RowIndex == this.dgvEndEditCell.RowIndex + 1
                        && dgvacc.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == this.dgvEndEditCell.ColumnIndex)
                    {
                        int iColNew;
                        int iRowNew;
                        if (this.dgvEndEditCell.ColumnIndex >= dgvacc.ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            iColNew = 0;
                            iRowNew = dgvacc.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            iColNew = this.dgvEndEditCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
                            iRowNew = this.dgvEndEditCell.RowIndex;
                        }
                        dgvacc.CurrentCell = dgvacc[iColNew, iRowNew];
                    }
                }
                this.dgvEndEditCell = null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Override the Form's `ProcessCmdKey` to trap the `Keys.Enter` presses and select the next cell **IF** the gird is focused **OR** the `DataGridView.EditingControl` property is not `null/Nothing`.

```cs
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }     

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if ((dataGridView1.Focused || dataGridView1.EditingControl != null)
            && keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SelectNextCell();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    private void SelectNextCell()
    {
        var col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        var row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (col < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1) col++;
        else
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

        // Optional, select the first cell if the current cell is the last one.
        // You can return; here instead or add new row.
        if (row == dataGridView1.RowCount) row = 0;

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col, row];
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Derive a new class from `DataGridView` and do the same except the *focus* and *EditingControl* checks:

```cs
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class DataGridViewEx : DataGridView
{
    public DataGridViewEx() : base() { }

    // Optional to enable/disable this feature...
    public bool SelectNextCellOnEnter { get; set; } = true;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (SelectNextCellOnEnter && keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            SelectNextCell();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }

    private void SelectNextCell()
    {
        var col = CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        var row = CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (col < ColumnCount - 1) col++;
        else
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }

        if (row == RowCount) row = 0;

        CurrentCell = this[col, row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another late response here.

There are two modes where an ENTER key may be intercepted:

1. If the cell is in editing mode, the cell itself must handle the key
2. If not, the DGV must handle the key

Both in order to prevent the cell progression upon ENTER key.

Here is a subclassing solution of a 'DataGridViewCustomColumn'
that acts like a 'DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' but suppresses
ENTER-Key progression for both cases.

```
public class DataGridViewCustomColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
  public DataGridViewCustomColumn() : base(new DataGridViewCustomCell()) { }

  public class DataGridViewCustomCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
  {
    public override Type EditType => typeof(DataGridViewCustomEditingControl);

    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged() {
      // register key down handler at DGV once
      var dgv = DataGridView;
      if (dgv != null && !dgvs.Contains(dgv)) {
        dgvs.Add(dgv);
        dgv.KeyDown += HandleKeyDown;
      }
    }

    private static HashSet<DataGridView> dgvs = new();

    private static void HandleKeyDown(object s, KeyEventArgs e) {
      if (s is not DataGridView dgv) return;
      if (dgv.CurrentCell is not DataGridViewCustomCell) return;

      if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) {
        //dont proceed to other cell
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
  }

  public class DataGridViewCustomEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
  {
    protected DataGridView Dgv => (DataGridView)Parent?.Parent;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message m, Keys keyData) {
      var dgv = EditingControlDataGridView;
      if (keyData == Keys.Enter && dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode) {
        // end edit but dont proceed to other cell
        dgv.EndEdit();
        dgv.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
        return true;
      }
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref m, keyData);
    }
  }
}
```